# Cart items not shows in cart on using Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, rest-api, guest

I am using Magento 2 REST API for add to cart item in guest but after checking on cart page it's just empty.
Why it is empty.

```
http://127.0.0.1/mag/rest/V1/guest-carts/Hkt4RC38lJX1rAalFoPlsk2suRwb8Fnp/items
```

when i check the response of that call it gives me

```
[
{
    "item_id": 41,
    "sku": "test",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "price": 100,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "Hkt4RC38lJX1rAalFoPlsk2suRwb8Fnp"
}
]
```

that response means the product is in cart but doesn't show on frontend.
Any idea regarding that.
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: By frontend you mean in browser? if yes then please check the page you are referring in browser contains same guest cart session id as you are using in rest api.

Comment: @RahulBarot thanks for your response yes i mean browser cart page and i have saved the value in session like $_SESSION["cartId"] = $b; here $b is random string which is generated from http://127.0.0.1/mag/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/ here are an example for that string is "YAfrS3qbN01AaX1AyWOrQBIdDMmJKisv" but still it doesn't show any items in cart.will you please help.

Comment: do you have multi websites or multi stores?

Comment: No @DianaBotean Single store and single website.

Comment: roger that. are you creating a new cart and then adding items to it? or is this an already existing cart?

Comment: @DianaBotean Creating a new cart like virtual by using REST API

Answer (score 0):

You can use this api to check whether the product has been added to the cart or not. If the api returns the correct cart and the product you added earlier please clear the cache and try again.
http://127.0.0.1/mag/rest/V1/guest-carts/Hkt4RC38lJX1rAalFoPlsk2suRwb8Fnp/

Answer (score 0):

On a quick thought on the matter, this looks like a normal behavior.

When you are accessing the browser, you are basically just **another guest user**, who will generate **another cart ID** and not the one you added from your api call.

I don't think that you can simply load another user's cart by its ID, since this is a matter of private content and the whole mechanism is more complicated than that since it involves the session, the local storage, cart versioning and so on.

> Versioning works as follows:
>
> 1. The user performs some action, such as adding to a cart, that results
>    in an POST or PUT request to the Magento application.
> 2. The server
>    generates the private_content_version cookie for this user and returns
>    the response to the browser.
> 3. JavaScript interprets the presence of the
>    private_content_version cookie to mean that private content is present
>    on the page, so it sends an AJAX request to the Magento server to get
>    the current private content.
> 4. The server’s reply is cached in the
>    browser’s local storage. Subsequent requests with the same data version are retrieved from
>    local storage.
> 5. Any future HTTP POST or PUT request changes the value of
>    private_content_version and results in the updated content being
>    cached by the browser.